# S3 trigger on Lambda worked before this morning not anymore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that gets trigger by any objects ending with `.csv` (using the suffix) that is created in a s3 bucket.

This was working fine until about 5hrs ago when the trigger simply stopped working. I did not change anything on the configuration.

I tried removing the trigger and adding again, but the function just won't trigger. Is it possible I reached a limit or something? or something isn't working anymore in s3/lambda?

Comment: did u get the chance to know what was wrong cuz I have the same issue?

Comment: it keeps happening from time to time but never find out why :/

Answer (score -1):

Did you deployed it as a code ? can you redeploy it ? Was it with Cloud formation stacks ? What are the stacks showing ?

If you work with AWS web ui, go to the lambda and check under "triggers" is there something ?

In s3 bucket, under Properties and "event notification" is there your lambda ?

Check the logs if lambda was triggered, but had errors.

There still could be some security group problems, but this is where I would start. GL !